# How to save data as csv file from a dictionary containing keys and lists containing data to respective keys

Tags: python, csv

I need some help on how to save data as a csv file consisting of keys with respective data in colon form. My code does this only if the dictionary contains one key and one list, but if i have more keys and more lists, the code manages to save the keys as i want them, that is to say, as rows but the data from all lists is saved in the first key. 
Any ideas are really appreciated

I've tried googling most answers on csv file writing but I haven't found any that resolves my issue

The code is as follows:

```
with open('C:/Users/..../Voltage.csv','wb') as csvFile:
                output = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                output.writerow(voltdict.keys())
                for item,value in voltdict.iteritems():
                    for k in value:
                        output.writerow(localize_float([k])) 
            csvFile.close()
```

This an example of what i wish to accomplish:

```
key1 key2 keyn
123  232  253
245  398  ..n
```

Voltdict is my dictionary and it looks like this:

```
{'key1': [list1] 'key2': [list2] 'key:n' : [listn]}
```

This is an example of what i get with more than one key and more than one list

```
key1 key2 key:n
122
245
232
398
253
..n
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Is there any other issue?

Comment: Hey Novice, your answer almost answered my question but i have a slight issue, Now all data ends up in one colon, do you have any tips on how to store it in different colons?

Comment: Hope I answered your remaining issues

Comment: It works perfect now @Novice, Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your dictionary to a pandas dataframe, then use to csv. See below

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(my_dictionary)
df.to_csv(file_name)
```

When creating a DataFrame, simply pass a dictionary into the function, and the data should be structured properly. Here is an example

```
list1=[2,3,4]
list2=[2,3,4]
listn=[1,2,3]
dictionary={'key1': list1, 'key2': list2, 'keyn' : listn}
df=pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

which outputs

```
   key1  key2  keyn
0     2     2      1
1     3     3      2
2     4     4      3
```

Looking at your code i see two problems. First, you need commas between your keys when you create a dictionary. Second, if `list1`, `list2` and `listn` are already lists when they are defined, then you don't need additional brackets around them. Doing this would create a list of lists where the out list has only one entry.

If you have any other issues let me know